# Error in installing angularjs-server module

Tags: python, angularjs, node.js

On installing angularjs-server via

> npm install angularjs-server

command, I am getting below error:

[image: error on installing angularjs-server before python installed]

on installing python I get following error:

[image: error on installing angularjs-server after python installed]

What is the reason to not install angularjs-server? Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Install a visual studio express 2013(desktop with c++ redist), this will help.

or

 you can refer following [link](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/issues/60).